# Can't read file content to variable via cronjob

Tags: bash, shell, cron

My program where I try to read the content of a file in a variable.

```bash
root@pi:/tmp> cat /bin/dnsupdate
#!/bin/sh

set -xv

ip="$(cat /tmp/ip)"
echo $ip
exit 0
```

When I run the program in a shell, it works perfectly.

```bash
root@pi:/tmp> dnsupdate

ip="$(cat /tmp/ip)"
+/bin/dnsupdate:5> ip=+/bin/dnsupdate:5> cat /tmp/ip
+/bin/dnsupdate:5> ip=92.192.52.164
echo $ip
+/bin/dnsupdate:6> echo 92.192.52.164
92.192.52.164
exit 0
+/bin/dnsupdate:7> exit 0
```

Now adding a cronjob and logging the script output.

```bash
root@pi:/tmp> crontab -l
#m   h    d    m    w    cmd
*    *    *    *    *    dnsupdate >>/tmp/dns 2>>/tmp/dns
```

```bash
root@pi:/tmp> cat dns

ip="$(cat /tmp/ip)"
+/bin/dnsupdate:5> ip=+/bin/dnsupdate:5> cat /tmp/ip
+/bin/dnsupdate:5> ip=''
echo $ip
+/bin/dnsupdate:6> echo

exit 0
+/bin/dnsupdate:7> exit 0
```

Also tried `#!/bin/zsh` as shebang since my default shell is zsh and stuff like `ip=$(</tmp/ip)` but still no luck. Why is there no content in the variable when the script runs via cron?

Comment: Permissions error on the `/tmp/ip` file?

Comment: `chmod 777 /tmp/ip` and still the same result

Comment: Could you have your script do `ls -l /tmp/ip`? I'd be curious to know if the cron version knows the file is non-empty.

Comment: Obvious question. When this happens `/tmp/ip` does **have** contents right?

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 14 21:56 /tmp/ip` from cron, `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 May 14 21:56 ip` from shell. Why is it empty for cron?

Comment: Those output are from the same time (or as close as possible)? Something isn't just zeroing the file on you? Do you have per-use temp directories or anything? (Using a "random" file in `/tmp` isn't exactly a robust or reliable solution to begin with.)

Comment: I really thought the other cronjob updating the file was still disabled :/. After adding `sleep 10` to the script it works now. I want to use my IP in some other scripts too, so I really need that file to prevent flooding ifconfig.sh with too much requests. But to avoid something like this to happen again when accessing the file from multiple scripts, is there a more fail-safe and elegant way besides "try read file, if var empty sleep x sec and try again"?

Comment: cron jobs run as a daemon user and don't have a PATH set.  Try expanding a full path to /bin/cat and /bin/echo.